# How to mix sql consults to make conditions to another one

Tags: sql

I've the following tables

**series_trailers**:

```
ID EPISODEID  CONTENT  AUTHOR
-----------------------------
1  122383    url1     Peter
2  9999      url2     Ana
3  923822    stuff    Jhon
4  122384    url3     Drake
```

**series_episodes**:

```
ID      TITLE           SERIESID
--------------------------------
122383  Episode 1       23
9999    Somethingweird  87
923822  Randomtitle     52
122384  Episode 2       23
```

**series**:

```
ID   TITLE
-------------------
23   Stranger Things
87   Seriesname
512  Sometrashseries
```

As you can see there are three tables: one with the series info, one with the series' episodes and another one which contains urls that redirect to the episode's trailers. I'd like to get the lastest rows from `series_trailers` but without repeating the series where they're from.
I've tried with `SELECT DISTINCT EPISODEID FROM series_trailers ORDER BY id DESC`but there are two rows with the same episodes' series so I'll get the seriies `Stranger things` twice. Summing up I'd like to display the lastest series with new urls but I don't want to get duplicated series (that's what i'd get with the sql above)

EDIT: **What I'm supposed to get:**

Last updated series:

- Stranger Things
- Seriesname
- Sometrashseries

**What I'd get with my sql code:**

- Stranger Things
- Seriesname
- Sometrashseries
- Stranger Things (again)

Comment: Can you update your question with your expected output?

Comment: Which dbms????????

Comment: Is your question answered? Thanks!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton edited

Comment: @Jakob trying right now

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the trailer with the highest ID for each episode. This answer is based on the assumption that the episode with the highest ID is the latest one.

```
select id, content from series_trailer where episode_id in 
  (select max(id)
   from series_episodes
   group by seriesid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, here is the latest trailer for the latest episodes (latest as in the highest `series ID` / `series_trailer ID`, so most likely added lastest).

```
WITH MostRecentTrailers
AS (
    SELECT MAX(st.ID) "TRAILERID"
        ,s.ID "SERIESID"
        ,s.TITLE "SERIESTITLE"
    FROM series_trailers st
    JOIN series_episodes se ON se.ID = st.EPISODEID
    JOIN series s ON s.ID = se.SERIESID
    GROUP BY s.ID
        ,s.TITLE
    ORDER BY s.ID DESC
    )

SELECT *
FROM MostRecentTrailers mrt
JOIN series_trailers st ON st.ID = mrt.TRAILERID
```

Let me know if that does it for ya.

Edit: Fixed some typo mistakes.

Comment: Needn't to be the lastest episode, just the lastest trailer added (higgest ID). This trailer belongs to a episode, that episode to a series. A series has more than one episode so if two trailers are added to a two different episodes but those belonging to the same series get just the serie once